# Google Maps address form integration sending white screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have a website build in PHP smarty + I added also bootstrap. The problem is that when I add this script for integrating Google maps, I get White Screen.

If I remove the inline script (HERE IS THE ABOVE SCRIPT) Blank screen disappears.
I also tried removing each function one by one from the inline script and still got blank screen. Did not work until I removed all functions.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 var placeSearch, autocomplete;

var componentForm = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};

function initialize() {
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      (document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
      { types: ['geocode'] });
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    fillInAddress();
  });
}

function fillInAddress() {
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
}

function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(
          position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
      autocomplete.setBounds(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(geolocation,
          geolocation));
    });
  }
}
</script>
```

The main elements targeting the google maps module of the webpage would look like this:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">HERE IS THE SCRIPT ABOVE</script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="height: 100px; width=100px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">initialize();</script>
```

My full page can be found here http://pastebin.com/XjnZRa5i.
Please help me I am a noob in javascript.

**EDIT 2**

I managed to place the auto-suggest id and it is working and auto-suggesting. But it is not auto filling the form. When I start the console and type a country in the field with the `id="autocomplete"` I get in the console `TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null` on line 27 in the javascript, here --> `document.getElementById(component).value = '';` within the function `fillInAddress()`.
Current HTML looks like this http://pastebin.com/nYNbt7wv.
The part that I am focusing is:

```
<div class="form">
<label class="title-submit">{'webmasterSubmitWebsite_adress'|lang}</label>
<div class="infos-submit"><input id="autocomplete" onfocus="geolocate()" type="text" class="input_text_large_submit" name="address"/></div>
</div><br>
<div class="form">
<label class="title-submit">{'webmasterSubmitWebsite_postal_code'|lang}</label>
<div class="infos-submit"><input id="postal_code" class="input_text_small" name="zipCode" disabled="true" /></div>
</div><br>
<div class="form">
<label class="title-submit">{'webmasterSubmitWebsite_city'|lang}</label>
<div class="infos-submit"><input id="locality" class="input_text_large_submit" name="city" disabled="true" /></div>
</div><br>
<div class="form">
<label class="title-submit">{'webmasterSubmitWebsite_country'|lang}</label>
<div class="infos-submit"><input id="country" class="input_text_large_submit" name="country" disabled="true" autocomplete="on" /></div>
</div><br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this line of code:

```
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    (document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
    { types: ['geocode'] });
```

In particular this expression:

```
document.getElementById('autocomplete')
```

That is looking for an element whose `id` attribute is `autocomplete`. Specifically, it wants an `input` element. (BTW you don't need the extra parentheses around this expression.)

Do you have an element like this anywhere in your HTML?

```
<input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter a city or address" />
```

Once you add that your autocomplete should start working.

Now, how did I find that, and how can you find problems like this yourself? Have you used the JavaScript debugger in Chrome or other browsers? That is the key to finding errors like this.

I added this statement at the beginning of the `initialize()` function:

```
debugger;
```

Then I loaded the page with the Chrome developer tools open. It stopped on that statement, and then I stepped through the code (stepping over function calls). There was an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null` message when I stepped over the `Autocomplete()` call.

The likely cause of that message inside `Autocomplete()` would be that you passed a `null` value into the function. So I pasted this part into the Chrome console and ran it:

```
document.getElementById('autocomplete')
```

Sure enough, it evaluated to `null`, and from there it's easy to figure out what the problem is.

There is a lot of great info on the Chrome developer tools and similar tools for other browsers. I would start with this [introduction to the Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/index), and especially this section about [debugging JavaScript](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging).

Comment: Hey Thanks for the answer, it seams it's because I am using smarty php and I needed to wrap my code within the {literal}{/literal} tags. But will also try your idea because map is blank now.

Comment: Glad to help. I don't see any code that initializes the map, so I would expect the map to be blank.

Comment: Ok, I think I miss-understood the concept, I was expecting also a Google Map that would point automatically to the address that is getting auto-suggested and opposite (when the user pins the address on the map to get automatically written in the fields). Is there anywhere a documentation for this?

Comment: Hey Micheal, could you please tell me why I get a value of NUll. Please check EDIT 2. I implemented it like here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform. Where am I mistaking?

Comment: Use the JavaScript debugger. Open the Chrome console and go to the Sources tab. Find the gray "stop sign with vertical bars" icon on the right. When you hover the mouse over it, it will say "Pause on exceptions." Click that icon to turn it blue. Now the JavaScript debugger will stop when it hits the exception. (If it doesn't, try checking the Pause on Caught Exceptions box.) When it stops on the error, what is the value of the `component` variable? That is the DOM element you're missing.

Comment: Another tip: Instead of putting the raw PHP code in Pastebin, use [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to put up a running test version of your page. You won't have PHP or Smarty available, but that's OK, you can hand-code the corresponding HTML. If you like, you can start by forking a [Maps API fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geary/b7UNb/) of mine and updating it with your own code. This will make it a lot easier for people to help you out.

Once you get it working in jsFiddle, you can update your PHP/Smarty code to match that.

Comment: Ok, solve it, understood how it work, I need to comment the components from component form that I don't have them in the html. Odd thing. Thanks Michael, indeed a DOM problem.

Comment: BTW, I also have a question regarding google maps over here that may be useful to a lot of people. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23841974/integrating-google-maps-place-form-into-the-autocomplete-address-form-javascript